# Why miners choose to verify the transactions of the incoming block?

Tags: mining, verify, contract-verification, reward

I want to know whether miners can get rewards for verifying transactions in blocks broadcast by other nodes? If there is no reward, why would miners choose to verify transactions?

I am very confused about this. Hope you can give me some help, thanks!

Comment: I see you have a lot of questions about mining. That's great. Maybe you should have a look at the white/beige/yellow papers.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I have been learning Ethereum for a short time. I will study the yellow paper in the future.

Comment: I would advise to start with white and beige ones first.

Comment: Thank you for your enthusiastic reply today, which has benefited me a lot. I will take time to study the white and beige paper first. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Miners don't get any rewards for verifying candidate blocks. However they allow to add a new block to the chain, and therefore gain the opportunity to mine the next block and get its reward.